# Change what is returned on screen by class instance

Tags: python

Lets say I have a class Hello, and I do the following:

```
>> a = Hello()
>> a
```

This will return the following:

```
<__main__.Hello instance at 0x123abc>
```

How do I change the class to return something else (like an instance variable for example)?

Comment: what's your plan with this? Try to call one function from that class then!

Comment: Why would you want a class call to return something that isn't a class?

Comment: No reason, just wanted to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add:

```
class Hello(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "HI"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Hi"


>>> a = Hello()
>>> a           --> calls __repr__ method
Hi        
>>> print a     --> calls __str__ method
HI
```

Comment: This doesn't change what `Hello()` returns.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi, I wasn't finish editing.

Comment: That still doesn't change what `Hello()` returns, only what is displayed.

Comment: This is correct. Hello() cannot return an instance variable

Comment: @IsmailBadawi well I think that is what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Ah, yeah, I can see how the question might read that way. I think the word "return" is ambiguous here. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of answering the *EXACT* question being asked, what you're asking about, "change what's returned by calling a class", is roughly the semantics of a metaclass.

So, for the sake of argument, lets suppose we want to have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
    def __init__(self, bar):
        print "Hello from", self
        self.bar
```

actually satisfy:

```
>>> myBar = object()
>>> myFoo = Foo(myBar)
Hello from <__main__Foo object at 0x...>
>>> myFoo is myBar
True
```

Specifically, we have a real class, which really gets instantiated when called upon, but the return value is something else, we can do that, so long as `MyMeta` looks about like so:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super(MyMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.bar
```

Of course, I would not do this.