# How do you call an instance of a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, call

This is inspired by a question I just saw, "Change what is returned by calling class instance", but was quickly answered with `__repr__` (and accepted, so the questioner did not actually intend to call the instance).

Now calling an instance of a class can be done like this:

```
instance_of_object = object() 
instance_of_object()
```

but we'll get an error, something like `TypeError: 'object' object is not callable`.

This behavior is defined in the CPython [source here.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/call.c#L80)

So to ensure we have this question on Stackoverflow:

> How do you actually call an instance of a class in Python?

Comment: Thanks for making Stackoverflow even better. Here, have an upvote :)

Comment: For reference, the inspiring question is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24253448/2297365).

Comment: OK, this should become a canonical question.

Comment: Thank you! I saw this happening in some source code and was wondering what was happening here.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You call an instance of a class as in the following:

```
o = object() # create our instance
o() # call the instance
```

But this will typically give us an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'object' object is not callable
```

How can we call the instance as intended, and perhaps get something useful out of it?

We have to implement Python special method, `__call__`!

```
class Knight(object):
    def __call__(self, foo, bar, baz=None):
        print(foo)
        print(bar)
        print(bar)
        print(bar)
        print(baz)
```

Instantiate the class:

```
a_knight = Knight()
```

Now we can call the class instance:

```
a_knight('ni!', 'ichi', 'pitang-zoom-boing!')
```

which prints:

```
ni!
ichi
ichi
ichi
pitang-zoom-boing!
```

And we have now actually, and successfully, **called** an instance of the class!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the `object` class has no `__call__` method (you can check that with "dir(object)"). When you create an instance of a class the `__init__` method is called and when you call the instance, the `__call__` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Up Votes for Everyone!
Thanks for posting the question and thanks for answering.

I thought I would just share my implementation in case that helps others ...

I have a class (called RTS) and it contains an SQL Query that I access using a 'get'.  The class works fine as an independent endpoint.  Now I want to call that class from within the program.

Using the answer above I added the following:

```py
class RTS(Resource):
    def __call__(self):
        print("In RTS")

    def get(self, user_id):
        try: ...
```

In order to call the class from elsewhere in the program I added:

```py
getGR = RTS.get(self, user_unique_id)
```

Voila - I got the same info I could check on Postman returned within the program.