# Is there a __repr__() like method for a python class?

Tags: python

I'm solving a funny problem that requires to define a class that can be called like this:
 `class Chain(2)(3)(4)`
And it should print out the multiplication of all arguments.
I ended up a solution like this:

```
class Chain():
    calc = 1 
    def __new__(cls, a=None):
        if a:
            cls.calc = cls.calc*a
            return cls
        else:
            return cls.calc
```

This works fine and `self.calc` is equal to 24 but i have a wrong representation `<class '__main__.Chain'>`.
Is there anyway to have representation of *multiplication* instead of class name like what we have in `__repr__` for objects?

*note*: The call arguments count has no limits and may be different on each call.

Comment: Why isn't this solved on the instance level? i.e. implement `__call__`, not `__new__`...

Comment: Please explain your unique requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to answer your direct question from the title:

As everything in Python, classes are too - objects. And just like classes define how ***instances*** are created (what attributes and methods they will have), metaclasses define how ***classes*** are created. So let's create a metaclass:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.calc)

class Chain(metaclass=Meta):
    calc = 1

    def __new__(cls, a=None):
        if a:
            cls.calc = cls.calc*a
            return cls
        else:
            return cls.calc

print(Chain(2)(3)(4))
```

This will print, as expected, `24`.

---

A few notes:

1. Currently `Meta` simply accesses a `calc` attribute blindly. A check that it actually exists could be done but the code above was just to make the point.
2. The way your class is implemented, you can just do `Chain(2)(3)(4)()` and you will get the same result (that's based on the `else` part of your `__new__`).
3. That's a weird way to implement such behavior - you are returning the class itself (or an int...) from the `__new__` method which should return a new ***object*** of this class. This is problematic design. A classic way to do what you want is by [making the objects callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253761/how-do-you-call-an-instance-of-a-class-in-python):

```py
class Chain():
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.calc = a

    def __call__(self, a=None):
        if a:
            return self.__class__(self.calc * a)
        else:
            return self.calc

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.calc)

print(Chain(2)(3)(4))
```

This solves your problem of even needing to do what you want, because now you just implement the class' `__repr__` (because now each call in the chain returns a new ***object***, and not the class itself).

Comment: This was a very nice explanation about metaclass and also better implementation at object level.